# A special case of integrating over a marginal distribution

Tags: probability

Let $F(x \mid y, z)$ denote the conditional distribution of $x$ conditional on $y$ and $z$.  Suppose that
\begin{equation}
  \forall (y, y') \forall z, \quad F(x\mid y, z) = F(x\mid y', z).
\end{equation}

Is it the case that
\begin{equation}
  \forall (y, y'), \quad F(x\mid y) = F(x\mid y')?
\end{equation}

The reason I ask is because I am reading a paper that assumes that $y$ and $z$ are independent in order to prove this result, but I feel that assumption is unnecessary.  For example if $z$ is a continuous random variable, then for all $(y, y')$ we have
\begin{align}
  F(x|y) &= \int_z F(x\mid y, z) \color{red}{f(z)} dz \\
  &= \int_z F(x\mid y',z) \color{red}{f(z)} dz \\
  &= F(x\mid y'),
\end{align}
$\color{red}{\text{Where $f$ is the marginal distribution of $z$.}}$

If $z$ is discrete, then let $I$ be an index set that is either finite or countably infinite. We have
\begin{align}
  F(x|y) &= \sum_{i \in I} Pr(z=i)F(x|y, z=i) \\
  &= \sum_{i \in I} Pr(z=i)F(x|y', z=i) \\
  &= F(x|y')
\end{align}

We could treat random variables that are neither discrete nor continuous in the measure theoretic framework with a little extra notation.

**NOTE** that the text in red was added in response to an answer, which highlighted a mistake in the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That formula you are using is incorrect. The correct way (in the real
absolutely continuous case just to simplify as you do in your question) is
\begin{eqnarray*}
  F \left( x|y \right) & = & \int_{- \infty}^x f \left( \xi |y \right)
  \mathrm{d} \xi\\
  & = & \int_{- \infty}^x \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} f \left( \xi, z|y \right)
  \mathrm{d} z \mathrm{d} \xi\\
  & = & \int_{- \infty}^x \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} f \left( \xi |z, y \right)
  f \left( z \right) \mathrm{d} z \mathrm{d} \xi\\
  & \neq & \int_{- \infty}^x \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} f \left( \xi |z, y
  \right) \mathrm{d} z \mathrm{d} \xi\\
  & = & \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} F \left( \xi |z, y \right) \mathrm{d} z
\end{eqnarray*}
where the last line follows by Fubini.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that I missed off the $f(z)$. However, I am not sure that the actual fact is wrong.  Don't we have $F(x|y) = \int_z F(x|y, z) f(z) dz = \int_z F(x|y', z) f(z) dz = F(x|y')$, where $f$ is the marginal distribution of $z$. The intuition is as follows. By the assumption in the first display $F(x|y, z) = F(x|y', z)$ for all $y, y', z$. Thus if we integrate against the marginal distribution of $z$ on both sides, then equality is preserved.

Comment: @AlexOlssen I saw a mistake in your question and did not look any further. Now, that's done, the answer is yes, it is correct.